# Why SSMS 17.x and further doesn't support SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

Everything is in the title, I can't find why did they remove this function on 17.x version.

I quote:

> SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) – SSMS version 17.x or later does not support connecting to the legacy SQL Server Integration Services service.
> [Source](https://seniordba.wordpress.com/2019/06/10/free-download-sql-server-management-studio-18-0/)

So as a purpose of training on this feature, I have got to install SSMS and SQL SERVER 16.x for example isn't it?

I have installed 16.5 version so I have to find exactly same version for SQL server which means SQL SERVER 2016. Did I understand correctly please?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: They didn't remove it. The key word is **legacy**. If you want to connect to SSIS 2016, use SSMS 2016. Or better yet, use SSISDB and then you don't need to connect to SSIS at all in SSMS..

Comment: Oh thank you i googled SSISDB and it seams that it is recomended to use it rather than SSIS in SSMS since 2012 version.
"Since the release of SQL Server 2012, the SSIS Catalog database, SSISDB, is the recommended way to store, manage, run, and monitor Integration Services packages. For details, see SSIS Catalog." --> https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15

So this is the reason why it is not supported anymore into SSMS since 17.x version

Comment: I regularly see this question. I'm curious as to what led you to try connecting to this service. Surely it's not in any documentation any more?

Comment: There *is* still documention at the moment, @Nick.McDermaid , but it's quite sparse now with the changes they made the to online docs design this year. I wouldn't be surprised if the SSIS package deployment models (File System/MSDB) will be removed in a future version of SQL Server.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I follow a 70-462 exam training course, it say me to connect to integration services by using SSIS... Based on the SQL SERVER 2012 version :| But at this moment everything that is into SQL SERVER 2012 is available in SQL SERVER 2017 or further as i can see because i run SQL SERVER 2017 and 2016

Comment: Yes that's a really old exam. If your objective is to learn SSIS, find a more modern tutorial. If your objective is to learn 'data' do a newer exam like dp-000 or dp-001

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Actually i am learning database administration and this course is excellent... I don't know what you have to reproach about it ... :|
Plus, it still the one that are proposed on the microsoft web-site when you want a certification on sql server :  https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/learning/mcsa-sql-certification.aspx

But if you have the link on a newer version i would love to get it please.

Comment: I guess there is no newer training that properly reflects usage of SSIS. Anyway good luck with your exam, just keep in mind that what you're learning reflects traditional on-premises type data systems which is fine because there's plenty around.

Answer (score 0):

As @Larnu said, use SSISDB rather than SSIS in SSMS since 2012 version.
This is recomended by microsoft documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15